# Read from terminal with tty echo

Tags: tcl, expect

I have this read routine:

```
proc getUserInput { query } {
    send_user "$query: "
    flush stdout  
    set data [gets stdin]
    send_user "\n"
    return $data
}
```

This works but does not echo on the tty. How to make the script echo on the tty? This function is called upon a control char trapped in an interact session.

Comment: In your script, have you used the `stty` command?

Comment: Perhaps when this function is invoked, the terminal is in raw mode. You may need to put `stty echo` as the first line in the proc.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You Mr Glen Jackman

I added the line..

```
exec stty echo
```

as the first line of the function and the echo was restored.

The new function is:

```
proc getUserInput { query } {
    exec stty echo
    send_user "$query: "
    flush stdout  
    gets stdin data
    return $data
}
```

Comment: The expect package includes a built-in `stty` command so you don't need to `exec`.